# Tortoise SVN not ancetrally related branches

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have a main delopment branch that was created by Copy To command in Repo Browser from Trunk to Branch folder.  Since then revisions keeps growing and has never merged into the Trunk.  The lastest revision number is 2148.  The other day we had to check out rev1020 in the development branch to a new BugFix branch(folder).  The bug is fixed and released to production directly without merging with Trunk or the Development branch.  The code is checked into the BugFix folder.  Now the HEAD is ready to be released.  I tried to merge the BugFix code into the lastest development branch.  However, Tortoise SVN complained that the two are not ancetrally related. Thus the mergy failed.  Does anyone know how to solve the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: I may be lost, but my understanding is your trying to merge a change from one branch to another branch in SVN? That may be the cause of ancestrally related issue as they have taken different paths. Try merging from the trunk into the branch or making sure all merging files are existant in both?

Answer (score 0):

@Nick,

These are from the same branch.  Just the BugFix is based on an much older revsion.  Hope the picture explains better.[image]